# get public IP from a network that I was connected to earlier

Tags: macos, networking, osx-lion, logging

1 hour ago I was connected to my office WiFi network with my Macbook. Now I'm at home and need the public IP address from that office network because the dyndns update failed and I need to remote connect via VPN.

Are there any log files on OSX Lion, that store the public IP? DNS cache? safari cache? ssh or terminal cache?

Any ideas?

Comment: If you were sitting behind a NAT box, no chance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try the Console app under Applications/Utilities? It gathers most of the logs generated by the system. Search for the first few digits of your public IP or for terms like "mDNS" or "Firewall" which frequently records your IP.

If this failed, you may be able to find your IP through logs of websites, e.g. the session records kept by Gmail.

Comment: Just as a late feedback: gmail saves your last 10 connections (the tiny "details" link in the right button corner)